# Swift Generics and Protocol Extensions

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift2, xcode7

I have a protocol `Reusable`that has a static function `static func reuseId() -> String` and a protocol extension that defines the default implementation for the function. Then, I implemented a extension on `UITableViewCell` to conform to the `Reusable` protocol. I can now use the function on my TableViewCells without a problem: `SomeTableViewCell.reuseId()`.

The Problem I have is with Generics. I have a generic class that has a generic parameter of the type `UITableViewCell`:

```
internal class SomeClass<CellType: UITableViewCell>: NSObject { 
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to use the function specified in `Reusable` in my generic class on `CellType` but unfortunately this does not work as expected. The compiler always generates the error `Type 'CellType' has no member 'reuseId'`.

Does anybody know why this is happening? Is there a workaround?

I am using Xcode 7.0 with Swift 2.0.

Greetings from Germany

UPDATE: Here is some sample code that better shows my problem:

```
import UIKit

protocol Reusable {
    static func reuseId() -> String
}

extension Reusable {
    static func reuseId() -> String {
        return String(self).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
    }
}

extension UITableViewCell: Reusable { }

class SomeGenericClass<CellType: UITableViewCell> {
    func someFunction() {
        let reuseIdentifier = CellType.reuseId()
    }
}
```

This Code will generate the above error but I do not quite understand why this happens. I think the main difference to the sample code that **jtbandes** posted is that I use a static function.

---

UPDATE: The issue is fixed in Xcode 8.3 beta 2. The sample code above now works as expected (after migrating it to Swift 3 of course).

Comment: It would be more helpful if you post a (minimal) example of actual code instead of only describing the problem.

Comment: I added sample code to my original question that hopefully makes my question better to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting problem. Your code seems like it should work; you might want to [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Here's a workaround that seems to work correctly:

```
class SomeGenericClass<CellType: Cell> {
    func someFunction() {
        let reuseIdentifier = (CellType.self as Reusable.Type).reuseId()
    }
}
```

Comment: But CellType inherits from UITableViewCell which already conforms to Reusable. It seems to me that more information is needed, I could not reproduce the problem with a simple example.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, I guess I misread the question. Yes, more information is needed...

Comment: Thanks. I posted a radar 22776964. Your workaround seems to work fine for the time beeing, thus I will mark your answer as correct. I will update the question once Apple responded to the radar.

Answer (score 0):

Another (workaround) way to get what you need:

```
class GenericExample<CellType:UITableViewCell where CellType:Reusable>     
{
    func test() -> String {
        return CellType.reuseId()
    }
}

GenericExample<UITableViewCell>().test() // returns "UITableViewCell"
GenericExample<MyCell>().test() // returns "MyCell"
```

Comment: PS Original scenario is most likely a bug as the autocompletion model in XCode knows CellType has a resuseID() yet the compiler complains otherwise