# Swift Generic Unknown Member with Protocol Extension

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

If I have the following code:

```
protocol ObjectType {
    var title: String { get set }
}

extension ObjectType {
    var objectTypeString: String {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        return "\(mirror.subjectType)"
    }
}

class Object: ObjectType {
    var title = ""
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    private func someFunc<T: Object>(object: T) {
        print(object.objectTypeString)
    }
}
```

where `Object` conforms to `ObjectType`, you would expect that you can access `objectTypeString` on any `ObjectInstance`. But the compiler says that `Type T has no member objectTypeString` when that member is accessed on some generic type that inherits from `Object`, as shown in the code above. When the function is non-generic and just passes in an `Object` parameter, there's no issue. So why does have the parameter be generic make it so I can't access a member of the protocol that the conforming class should have access to?

I came across this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683681/swift-generics-and-protocol-extensions) but I'm not interested in workarounds, I'd just like to understand what it is about the generic system that makes my example not work. (Simple workaround is to do `<T: ObjectType>`)

Comment: So you're asking for an explanation on how this bug can happen?

Comment: On why it happens. Is it just a bug that should be defined with Apple? Or is there a legitimate reason it happens.

Comment: Obviously it's a bug, there's nothing wrong with the code, we can only hope it gets fixed soon and have to use workarounds until then

Comment: @startupthekid I don't think thats a bug. You need to cast object to ObjectType (object as ObjectType)

Comment: @LeoDabus it 100% is, if `Object: ObjectType` in the definition of the class, and there's an extension on `ObjectType`, because `Object` conforms to it implicitly, you should be able to access anything in the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong or i didn't understand your question completely, but i think you might be missing initiating "object".

your willing code maybe the code below:

```
    protocol ObjectType {
    var title: String { get set }
}

extension ObjectType {
    var objectTypeString: String {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        return "\(mirror.subjectType)"
    }
}

class Object: ObjectType {
    var title = ""
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    private func someFunc<T: Object>(object: T) {
        let object = Object()
        print(object.objectTypeString)
    }
}
```

but the thing is, even if we dont initiate the object, the auto complete brings the objectTypeString up! that's what i don't understand, and as you said maybe its where the bug happens!

hope it helps <3

Comment: Thanks but that's not the issue, I instantiate the instances external to someFunc, which is just a contrived example anyway.